# What is the best way to add a user to the sudoer group?

Tags: sudo

So far I have found four different ways to add a user to the sudoers group and not all methods work in all systems. 
Why so many different implementations?
What is the best?
What is the standard (i.e. work in most systems)?

Different implementations:

1. Adding the user to the 'wheel' group.
2. Adding the user to the 'sudo' group.
3. Editing the file /etc/sudoers
4. Editing the file /etc/sudoers using visudo

Comment: If you want to put somebody in a group you edit /etc/group.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two (main) ways you can authorize a user to run commands as root via sudo:

- declare that “Alice may run commands as root”;
- declare that “Alice is a sysadmin” and that “sysadmins may run commands as root”.

The way to declare “Alice is a sysadmin” is to make her a member of the sysadmins group, but there is no standard name for the sysadmins group (nor any obligation that there is a sysadmins group). Some traditional Unix systems have a group called [`wheel`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_%28Unix_term%29#Wheel_group), but often being in the wheel group is only a prerequisite for becoming root, and the user must also know the root password and run `su` (that's how BSD uses it, in particular). Some distributions, such as Ubuntu and Debian, include a group called `sudo` and a rule “members of the group `sudo` may run command as root” in their default configuration.

If `/etc/sudoers` (or a file in `/etc/sudoers.d`) contains a line like `%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`, then you can make a user a sudoer by adding them to the `sudo` group (`adduser alice sudo`). The name `sudo` isn't magical, you just have to match the entry in `/etc/sudoers`.

Never edit `/etc/sudoers` (or a file under `/etc/sudoers.d`) directly: if you make a syntax error, you would lock yourself out of root access. Always use `visudo` to edit that file. To choose the editor that `visudo` runs, set the `VISUAL` environment variable (or `EDITOR`, as long as `VISUAL` is unset). On a multiuser machine, using `visudo` has the additional advantage that it takes care of locking in case two administrators edit the file at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

`adduser username sudo` works for me -- but then, I use Debian which has a `sudoers` file that defaults to giving everyone in the `sudo` group sudo access.

Answer (score 1):

For `Ubuntu` I added `<somefile>` at `/etc/sudoers.d/` with the line:

```
<user> ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Using the command:

```
visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/<somefile>
```

This is recommended because it leaves the `/etc/suoders` file untouched and thus avoids a conflict (and the required subsequent manual resolution) across upgrades. See: [Why /etc/sodoers.d/](https://superuser.com/a/869145/56505)

Answer (score 0):

The method 2 and 4 will work on almost every Linux. Don't even try to use 3 on working system! It can damage the system. Method 1 can work, but don't have to.

Why you should use visudo instead of manually editing /etc/sudoers?

> Once I had root access I used visudo to fix the sudoers file. Why visudo? Because that’s the program YOU ARE SUPPOSED TO USE. Yes I am a bit angry, because the person that broke this server should have known better. Visudo is a lovely little program that checks the syntax of the sudoers file before you save it so that if you do something monumentally stupid you’ll know about it before it becomes a problem and prevents you from getting back into the system as root.

http://lickthesalt.com/2009/07/06/fail-why-you-should-always-use-visudo/

Comment: Exactly what is meant by *damage the system? `/etc/sudoers`* is a text file read by *`sudo`* to establish its permissions rules. *`sudo`* interprets certain syntax and formatting rules according to its *`api`. `visudo`* should reject any edits that don't conform to these standards, but editing the file otherwise is perfectly safe so long as the rules are obeyed. There is no mystery here.

Comment: @mikeserv see updated answer.

Comment: I read that article before, and it was actually the one i was thinking of when i wrote the above comment. Your answer still obfuscates what actually happens should you 'damage your system,' and, and at least as i perceive it, contributes to FUD. Sorry. But thats my perception.

Comment: And, visudo only protects you from syntactical errors - it's still possible to lock yourself out of the system with a bad sudoers configuration. So, you should still know how to get root without sudo. I usually edit /etc/sudoers with `vi` instead of `visudo`, write the file,  and test my sudo access before exiting `vi`. That way I can revert my changes if it doesn't work. This doesn't work with `visudo` since it edits a temp file. Though these days it's not much of an issue since nearly all of my servers are managed by Puppet, including the sudoers file.

Comment: I'm not at all sure that the `sudo` group is more portable than `wheel`. Do you have a reference to support that claim? I'm pretty sure `wheel` is more common than `sudo` in the non-Debian world.

Comment: @terdon altrough by default, users in `wheel` group have `sudo` access, it does not have to be true on all systems.

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering if `sudo` does. I'm guessing here, but my guess is that there are various systems that use `wheel` instead of the `sudo` group.